# How do install and configure Grid Infastructure on Windows>

Tags: oracle-12c, windows-10, oracle-grid-control

I'm studying for the 1Z0-062 exam with John Watson's exam guide and I'm trying to install Grid Infrastructure alongside my Dbhome.

The book seems to run an installer that displays a configuration command to run at the end of the grid installation, but I haven't been able to find one.

On the Oracle site, whenever I try to find a Windows download for the Grid Infrastructure, I'm simply redirected to the OUI for the 12c Database. Problem is, the OUI won't prompt for any command to run after the installation, and when I try to run it myself it gives out this error:
https://puu.sh/vOGBB/2b89dd17cb.PNG

This is the command in question: Grid_home/perl/bin/perl -I Grid_home/perl/lib -I Grid_home/crs/install 
Grid_home/crs/install/roothas.pl

What am I doing wrong?